# How to find out what version of EcmaScript introduced certain function?

Tags: javascript

Let's take for example `.replaceAll()`. It supports from ES11 as far as I heard.

Also, we have `.split()` and I can't find in which version it was introduced.

And so on...

Do we have a source of this information?

Comment: MDN used to list the version, but they don't anymore. If the change came from an official propsal, you can see the year here: https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/main/finished-proposals.md

Comment: It's interesting why did MDN stop doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning of the [editor's draft of the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/) starts with a bit of a potted history. You can often find this information there. For instance, in this case, searching the intro for `replaceAll` finds:

> ECMAScript 2021, the 12th edition, introduced the `replaceAll` method for Strings; `Promise.any`, a Promise combinator that...

For changes made since ES2015, you can find it in one of two places:

- For full proposals, the [finished proposals list](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/main/finished-proposals.md). It has a column on the right for the "Expected Publication Year" (which, when it refers to the past, is the actual publication year). For instance, looking at that list shows you `replaceAll` in ES2021, which matches (whew!) what the spec text says.
- For smaller changes that didn't go through the proposals process, you can find the commit that updated the specification in the [commit history](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/commits/main) and [pull history](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pulls).

There's also the [Compatiblity Tables](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) maintained by [kangax](https://twitter.com/kangax). If you look at the top of the page, you see **5** (for ES5), **6** (for ES6, which is ES2015), and **2016+** which has ES2016 onward, listed by publication year.

Comment: It's a real pity that MDN removed this from their pages. Linking the proposals and then the first spec in which it appeared was quite useful